# apache authentication not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I am trying to implement apache authentication, but getting following error when giving correct password

> access to /webalizer/ failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler.

If i give incorrect password it shows me

> user testusr: authentication failure for "/webalizer/": Password Mismatc

Following is my apache configs

```
<Directory /var/www/html/webalizer>
Order allow,deny
AuthName "Authorized Users Only."
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
require valid-user
Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

apache is running with apache user, following is file permissions of htpasswd

> -rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 46 Nov  2 14:46 /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd

What do i missing?

OS is AWS linux instance.

Comment: Try adding `AuthBasicProvider file` to make sure file-based auth is used.

Comment: I have added this but still same issue.